# ui-router get transition information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following scenario:

During resolve phase, sometimes on refresh some of the dependencies fail. While  catch the error on $rootScopeService and handle it gracefully, I need to know earlier in one (in a decorator implementation of the $exceptionHandler service) that I failed during the transition from one state to the other.

The $state service provides the transition which unfortunately is being populated after the resolves succeed so I can't use that.

Is there anything already implemented?

My current thoughts are on implementing an additional service or decorating the $state service to track either using the go function or simply setting the values by listening on the $state events.

Is there any logic already implemented that achieves this? (I mean in the library) or are there any other suggestions for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a poor man's solution but you could use something like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope) {
   $rootScope.targetState = toState })

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
    function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope){
         $rootScope.targetState = undefined })
```

And then in your in your resolve function, access the target state via something like:

```
function myResolve($rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope.targetState)
}
```

I have this working in an app of mine. The statechange monitoring is implemented in my app's run block.

Comment: How would you access the toState parameter.

Comment: Editing answer. It's statechangesuccess, not complete.

Comment: This is the solution I already proposed. The toState does not exist and some extention of a sort will need to happen. In any case the answer is a bit irrelevant to the question as it is already stated in the question itself.

Comment: Where doesn't the toState exist? I just tried this in my app with console.log(toState.name + " start") and console.log(toState.name + "success") and just console.log("resolve") and all works as expected.

Comment: I assume you mean from within the resolve you cannot access the state. That wasn't entirely clear from your question. I've modified the answer to accomplish this.

Comment: It does not exist outside the event. I want to know that I am in transition in between start and end. Outside of the state events. I any case I know how to do it by using events as stated in the question. My question is if there is any "other" way, like the transition property that would allow me to do it in order to avoid decorating the state service. Plus your solution polutes the rootScope.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: You obviously could clean up the $rootScope in your code later or perhaps hang it someplace else. I was just showing how to capture it. At any rate, I'm not sure what the current status of this is, but in December 2015 there was an alpha release that included a new injectable named $transitionto$ that looks like it does what you want: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0alpha0